# Constructing (x,y) from (x,0) and (0,y) using ruler and compass

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Maybe this is a dumb question and I missed the point of something, but...

I am reading an old set of notes from when I was in college and doing some of the old homework problems.  The first one I am working on defines a number, line, point or arc as *constructible* if you can create it using a ruler (with measurement) and compass construction.

OK.

The first problem, specifically, is to show that the point $(x,y)$ is constructible only if $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ are constructible.

I have an "idea" for the proof, but I am having trouble formalizing it with enough rigor.

> Pf/ Assume $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ are constructible.
>
> Sweep an arc of length $y$, centered at $(x,0)$.
>
> Sweep an arc of length $x$, centered at $(0,y)$.
>
> Their intersection is the point $(x,y)$.

$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

OK, this works really nicely when I'm the one drawing the diagram and know where $(x,y)$ is relative to $(x,0)$ and .  But the truth is, when I "sweep an arc", I am really making circles centered at the two points.  And those two circles will have 2, 1, or 0 intersections (though, I guess I can force 1 or 2 because of the triangle inequality).  So, I guess WLOG, we can just assume there are two intersection points.

So, my question is, how can I "distinguish" between the two intersection points so that I can claim I have constructed the point $(x,y)$?

Comment: Are you allowed to "sweep an arc of length $y$"?  How do you find the length $y$? If you are using "collapsible compass" rules then even if you have a length $y$ somewhere you cannot necessarily draw an arc with that radius without some more work.

Comment: Note that $(x,y)$ can only be determined from $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ if the origin $(0,0)$ is also known.

Comment: I suspect that the proof depends somehow on the definition of what it means to construct $(x,0)$ (or $(0,y)$). The obvious way seems to be that you start with given points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ (and perhaps $(0.1)$ to disambiguate which way the $y$ axis goes). Then you can use constructions for parallel and/or perpendicular lines to get to $(x,y)$ more or less directly from $(x,0)$ and $(0,y)$ without ambiguity.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem asks for the "only if" direction, so you should instead start from "Assume $(x,y)$ is constructible".

Comment: @JairTaylor: I meant an arc with radius x and y.  (I can see why arc-length would be confusing, sorry for the mixup).  And we can do that because, as you note, the origin is constructible so we just have to place the compass on 0 and (x,0), for example.

Comment: @DavidK: perhaps, but the notes didn't go into any of that and the hint is to draw arcs/circles.

Comment: Not an answer, but I made [a Desmos notebook](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lf0zkb2jyx) where you can drag around the point $(x, y)$ and watch where the other intersection point of the two circles $(x', y')$ moves. Observation: if you consider the initial points in the complex plane: $w = x$ and $z = yi$, then the intersection points are at $w+z$ and 
$$
\frac{w^2 + z^2}{w + z},
$$ 
which guarantees that there are always $2$ points.

Comment: There has to be at some point a definition of what it means for a point $(x,y)$ to be constructible. Otherwise the entire exercise is meaningless. It might not be defined the way I suggested, but it has to be defined somewhere. I just noticed that instead of a straightedge you have a "ruler (with measurement)" so maybe you don't need a set of initial points to give you a unit-distance reference. But if I'm not given any reference points, why can't I just pick a point on the paper and say, "There, that's $(x,y)$"?

Comment: @nomen oh, I just assumed that was what you meant.  That wasn't the problem, though. The issue is whether you can make the arc with a given radius. But noticing David's comment above, I would think with a ruler "with measurement" that it's kosher to take a distance between two points and use that as a radius elsewhere. That's not allowed in some constructions.

Comment: @SammyBlack: that desmos notebook is very cool.

Comment: @DavidK: the set of points I have to work with are 0, (x,0), (0, y), and anything I can construct from them using ruler and compass.  I guess maybe my question is partly about the ambiguity of the definition I am using, since maybe (x,y) counts just because it's one of the intersections between the two circles I built.  But it would be nice to figure out how to "point" at it specifically (somehow).

Comment: The idea that you have the point $(x,0)$ "to work with" seems to be contradictory to the "only if" nature of the statement that is to be proved. The "if" direction would be easy because then they would just be asking you to construct the fourth vertex of a rectangle, given the other three vertices.

Comment: The homework problem actually says iff.  Of course, if we assume that (x,y) exists and is an admissible point, we can project to the axes to show that (x,0) and (0,y) are admissible as well.  (But the fun part is figuring out how).  But the whole course of the 5 exercises is to show that there's a whole "algebra" of constructible points, starting with this iff.